# Visual Editor not working for user on multiple computers

Tags: content, editor, visual-editor

We are running 3.9.1, and haven't updated any plugins or our theme since the user started seeing an issue with a particular page. If the user opened up the page, nothing showed in the visual editor, unless they selected content, etc. If the user clicked to switch the editor, they had a 'switchEditors is not defined' error.

After searching for this JavaScript error, most people it either resolved on its own, an update fixed it, etc.

What is stranger - anyone else could edit this page just fine. Also, no matter what machine this person used, it showed the same issue, but only for them. User tried 3 browsers on one computer, 2 on another, and 1 on yet another machine.

Copying and pasting content from one page to another worked fine - so the content wasn't an issue (it appeared) either.

How could something like this follow a users account, and not the browser?

Comment: Have you pulled the site down to local development environment, disabled all plugins and switched to the default theme to verify it's not a plugin or theme conflict?

Comment: No, we were unable to. But no other users are seeing this, and this user can edit any other page fine.

Comment: Unable to?  I don't follow.  Do you not have access?  Disabling all plugins and switching to the default theme is the first thing you do when debugging WordPress issues, and you don't want to do that on your live site.